# Egarch interpretation of coefficients

Tags: r, garch

I ran an egarch(1,1) model. I have a negative alpha1 and a positive gamma1 (leverage effect). Does this mean good news is more volatile? Or do you interpret these two parameters combined, I've read the alpha1 indicates the size effect of shock and the gamma1 shows the sign effect? Is it sensible, or is it due to some modelling error (just a weird result)?